# App which transforms chess moves into chess positions

Tags: software, pgn, websites

I am interested is there an app which transforms written moves into chesd position? In other words, if I paste written chess game (for example  1. c3 d5 2. d4 Nf6 3. Nf3 Bg4 4. e3 e6 5. Be2 Be7 6. Ne5 Bxe2 7. Qxe2 Nbd7 8.
Nxd7 Qxd7 9. Nd2 c5 10. dxc5 Bxc5 11. O-O O-O 12. Kh1 a6 13. e4 dxe4 14. Nxe4
Qe7 15. Bg5 Bb6 16. Qf3 Bd8 17. Rad1 e5 18. Rd3 Qe6 19. Nxf6+ Bxf6 20. Bxf6 Qxf6
21. Qxf6 gxf6 22. Rd7 Rab8 23. Rfd1 Kg7 24. g4 Kg6 25. Kg2 f5 26. R1d6+ f6 27.
gxf5+ Kxf5 28. Rxh7 Rg8+ 29. Kf1 Rg4 30. Rf7 Rg6 31. h4 Rh6 32. h5 Rxh5 33.
Rfxf6+ Ke4 34. Ke2 b5 35. f3# 1-0) is there an app which will transform this algebraic notation into chess position because I am too lazy to do it with real pieces and board. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

What you're looking for is software/website that allows you to load or import PGN files.

The Lichess Analysis board, for example, supports exactly what you want: https://lichess.org/analysis -- below the board is a text area labelled "PGN", paste your moves in there and hit "Import PGN", and you can then navigate through your game.

All decent chess software can do this: SCID, ChessX, Chess.com, Chessbase. There are also PGN-specialised tools: ChessPad, PGN Edit.

Comment: Personally I prefer the online PGN viewer at caissa.com over the Lichess one, but YMMV (depending which additional features you like).

Answer (score 3):

My own website has two pages where you can paste chess notation and view it on an interactive chessboard and then save it as a link to be bookmarked or generate an animated image showing the whole game from start to end:

(1) old: https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/

(2) new: https://www.apronus.com/chess/puzzle/editor.php (PGN import tab)

Comment: I use this constantly. I also love the hidden feature that it can convert German notation and others into English notation.

Comment: I wrote the PGN parser many years ago. I forgot about that hidden feature. It is probably only available in the old version but perhaps I copied the old code into the new version. I really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The app Lucas Chess has this functionality. It can import a PGN file (even one containing multiple games, in which case it puts up a spreadsheet-like window from which you can pick a game). But you don't even have to make a PGN file to contain your notation. Just "copy" (Ctrl-C) the text of your moves, and use Lucas Chess's "Paste PGN" feature.